# Using EJS between script tags

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

I'm new to EJS and I would like some help with creating divs dynamically out of data rendered with EJS on button click.
In my express file:

```
res.render("user/profile.ejs", { posts: req.user.posts });
//posts is an array with elements having a similar structure to
/*"posts":[
    {
        "_id":{"$oid":"5cf9072b74cc8310803c89df"},
        "type":"Story",
        "subject/genre":"somethin",
        "content":"another thing",
        "date":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1559824171334"}}
    }
]*/
```

In my ejs file:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div style="float: right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm m-1 loadPosts-btn" id="All" style="width: 60px">All</button>   
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm m-1 loadPosts-btn" id="Idea" style="width: 60px">Ideas</button>    
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm m-1 loadPosts-btn" id="Story" style="width: 60px">Stories</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".loadPosts-btn").click(function(){
            $(".posts-row").remove();
            if($(this).attr("id") === "All"){
                <% posts.forEach(elem=>{ %>
                    document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0].innerHTML += 
                        `<div class="row posts-row" style="border: 1px solid black">
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class="post-container m-4 p-3">
                                    <h2>${elem.type}</h2>
                                    <h4>${elem["subject/genre"]}</h4>
                                    <p>${elem.content}<p>
                                    <small>${elem.date}</small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>`
                <% }) %>    
            };
        });
        $("#All").click();

    });
</script>
```

It shows an error: `elem is not defined`. which I think is normal because I didn't pass `elem` to `render()`.
Briefly, what I want is to add a `<div class="row">` to every post in the `posts` array when the button with `id="All"` is clicked. I don't know if I should do it in `<script>` tags or under the `<div class="row">` without `<script>` tags.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Instead of using EJS to generate JavaScript code that creates HTML elements, why not generate HTML elements directly and then, if you need to show/hide those elements, use e.g. a simple CSS class or `display` toggle?

Comment: Wouldn't it be slower than generating the Javascript?

Comment: In what way? You'd be generating about the same amount of code (a bit less in my estimation) so it wouldn't be slower to download. If you generate plain HTML the browser has to parse it and turn it into DOM nodes. If you generate JavaScript then the browser has to parse the JavaScript and then execute it, and *then* parse the HTML and turn it into DOM nodes (for `.innerHTML = ...`).